# Split strings in a flat array on the space between mixed-case words and all-caps words

Tags: php, arrays, split, uppercase

I have this array

```
$arr2 = array(
    "SUBTITLE",
    "Test Your Might RUNTIME",
    "1 hr 41 mins GENRE",
    "Science-Fiction/Fantasy SYNOPSIS",
    "his film adaptation of the wildly popular video game comes complete with dazzling special effects and plenty of martial arts action. LIGTHNING AND EFFECT"
);
```

And I would like to separate the words that are all upper case from the sentences that are lower. Like this.

```
$arr2 = array(
    "SUBTITLE",
    "Test Your Might",
    "RUNTIME",
    "1 hr 41 mins",
    "GENRE",
    "Science-Fiction/Fantasy",
    "SYNOPSIS",
    "his film adaptation of the wildly popular video game comes complete with dazzling special effects and plenty of martial arts action.",
    "LIGHTNING AND EFFECT"
)
```

How would I do this? If there is a way to do this with regex, that would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm it works as expected, but one way would be to do something like the following:

```
function splitter($jumbled) {
  $lowercase = [];
  foreach($jumbled as $element){
    $exploded = explode(" ", $element);
    foreach ($exploded as $word){
      if ($word == strtoupper($word)){
        $uppercase[] = $word;
      } else {
        $lowercase .= $word . ' ';
      }
    }
    $output[] = $uppercase;
    $output[] = rtrim($lowercase,' ');
  }
 return $output;
}
```

then just call the function with arr2: `splitter($arr2)`

(note: this returns the array as you requested, but it would be easier to use the array afterwords if you matched the corresponding values as an $uppercase => $lowercase key/value pair in the array being returned)

Comment: I dont see where you are defining lowercase

Comment: You're right -- edited to instantiate $lowercase.  Btw, looking at your comment in StackSlave's answer, you can simply change the $uppercase logic to same as the $lowercase logic to accommodate LIGHTNING AND SPECIAL EFFECTS

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
<?php
$a = ['SUBTITLE', 'Test Your Might RUNTIME', '1 hr 41 mins GENRE', 'Science-Fiction/Fantasy SYNOPSIS', 'his film adaptation of the wildly popular video game comes complete with dazzling special effects and plenty of martial arts action. LIGTHNING AND EFFECT'];
foreach($a as $v){
  if(preg_match('/(?:[A-Z]{2,}(?:\s+|$))+/', $v, $m)){
    foreach($m as $s){
      if($s === $v){
        $r[] = $s;
      }
      else{
        $r[] = str_replace($s, '', $v); $r[] = $s;
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    $r[] = $v;
  }
}
print_r($r);
?>
```

Comment: Does this handle cases like this? LIGHTNING AND SPECIAL EFFECTS. I shouldve include that in the question

Comment: @LeonardoEcheverria, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used a separator to join the cases whenever there is a change. I don't know what other kind of data you could be passing so I left the separator as a variable to be changed easily.

```
$separator = '<br>';

foreach($arr2 as $index => $str) {
  $str = explode(" ", $str);
  $final_string = '';
  $last_case = '';

  foreach($str as $word) {
    if ($word === strtoupper($word)) {
      if ($last_case == 'lower') $final_string .= $separator.$word;
      else $final_string .= $word . ' ';

      $last_case = 'upper';
    } else {
      if ($last_case == 'upper') $final_string .= $separator.$word;
      else $final_string .= $word . ' ';

      $last_case = 'lower';
    }
  }

  $arr2[$index] = explode($separator, trim($final_string));
}

$arr2 = array_reduce($arr2, 'array_merge', []);

print_r($arr2); // array ( 0 => 'SUBTITLE', 1 => 'Test Your Might ', 2 => 'RUNTIME', 3 => '1 hr 41 mins', 4 => 'GENRE', 5 => 'Science-Fiction/Fantasy', 6 => 'SYNOPSIS', 7 => 'his film adaptation of the wildly popular video game comes complete with dazzling special effects and plenty of martial arts action.', 8 => 'STARRING');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_reduce()` for a functional-style approach to return a result array with a different count than the input array.

Split on sequences of all-caps words, including their leading and trailing spaces.  Capture the sequence of words so that only the outermost spaces are lost while splitting.

Merge all newly generated elements with the result array as you iterate so that you end up with a flat array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EJrAb))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        fn($result, $v) => array_merge(
            $result,
            preg_split(
                '/ *\b([A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*)\b */',
                $v,
                0,
                PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
            )
        ),
        []
    )
);
```

Specifically tailored to your input which only has the all-caps words at the end of the string, you can use [`/ (\[A-Z\]+(?: \[A-Z\]+)*)$/`](https://3v4l.org/P594p) with the same effect.